# MFC Selected file information

Tags: c++, user-interface, image-processing, mfc

I'm trying to create an MFC application wherein the user can select a file from a file browser panel (like the left panel in windows explorer, but showing files as well), and information about that file can be displayed and edited (Again, similar to the information displayed in windows 7's explorer bottom panel). The files in question are going to be images of varying types (though for the time being only .bmp will be used).

I have created a file browser using `CMFCShellTreeCtrl`, and now need to get the program to check if the selected (highlighted/ clicked on) file in the browser panel is an image, and if so, retrieve various information (e.g. image size, dimensions, name, location, etc.), and pass it somewhere else so that I can display this information in text fields. Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it?

If I need to be more specific, let me know and I'll try to provide the information requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some imaging library for this. Since you are working with MFC, GDI+ looks like a good candidate. Start from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533814%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a bunch. With GDI+, will I be able to detect which file is selected in the browser as well, or is this purely for the image processing and information retrieval? If not, do you have any ideas about how to catch that?

Comment: With GDI+ you can handle an image file providing its file name. To detect which file is selected, you need to handle some CMFCShellTreeCtrl event and extract selected file name. Then you need to get file extension and try to open it using GDI+.